# Which of the four designs outlined in this question will yeild the best INSERT time?

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, database-design, sql-server-2014

Which of the following four database designs would give me better insert times?

**Design 1**

```
ActivityType
--------------
Id  -- (int primary key identity(1, 1))
ShortName -- (For e.g. 'Biking', 'Jogging', 'Singing', etc.)
ActivityDetailTableName -- ('Biking', 'Jogging', 'Singing', etc. Please 
                        --   see the activity detail tables below)


ActivityLog
------------
Id
ActivityTypeId
DateTimeWhenItHappened
ActivityDetailId NOT NULL -- The Id of the Biking or Jogging or Singing tables

ACTIVITY DETAIL TABLES

Biking
-------
Id
WhoWasBiking
ForHowLong
WhatBike
Color

Jogging
--------
Id
WhoWasJogging
ForHowLong
WhatShoesWereTheyWearing

Singing
--------
Id
WhoWasSinging
WhichSong
```

**Notes**

Please note that in **Design 1**, I have a foreign key field named `ActivityDetailId` in the `ActivityLog` table.

In this design, when an activity happens, I will first insert a row in one of the activity detail tables, get their `Id` and insert a row in the 'ActivityLog`table with the 'ActivityDetailId` as the Id of the newly created row in the relevant activity detail table.

**Design 2**

```
ActivityType
--------------
Id  -- (int primary key identity(1, 1))
ShortName -- (For e.g. 'Biking', 'Jogging', 'Singing', etc.)
ActivityDetailTableName -- ('Biking', 'Jogging', 'Singing', etc. Please 
                        --   see the activity detail tables below)


ActivityLog
------------
Id
ActivityTypeId
DateTimeWhenItHappened
ActivityDetailId NULL


ACTIVITY DETAIL TABLES

Biking
-------
Id
WhoWasBiking
ForHowLong
WhatBike
Color
ActivityLogId

Jogging
--------
Id
WhoWasJogging
ForHowLong
WhatShoesWereTheyWearing
ActivityLogId

Singing
--------
Id
WhoWasSinging
WhichSong
ActivityLogId
```

**Notes**

Please note that in this design, just like in **Design 1**, here in **Design 2**, I have retained the `ActivityDetailId` field in the `ActivityLog` table. However, the field is nullable this time.

In addition, I have maintained another foreign key named `ActivityLogId` in each of the activity detail tables that links back the activity detail to the activity log.

To insert a row in this design, when a new activity happens, I will first insert a new row in the `ActivityLog` table inserting a `NULL` value into the `ActivityDetailId` column.

Then I will insert a new row in the relevant activity detail tables properly inserting the `ActivityLogId`, and then go back to the newly inserted row in the `ActivityLog` tables and update the value of the `ActivityDetailId`.

**Design 3**

```
ActivityType
--------------
Id  -- (int primary key identity(1, 1))
ShortName -- (For e.g. 'Biking', 'Jogging', 'Singing', etc.)
ActivityDetailTableName -- ('Biking', 'Jogging', 'Singing', etc. Please 
                        --   see the activity detail tables below)


ActivityLog
------------
Id
ActivityTypeId
DateTimeWhenItHappened

ACTIVITY DETAIL TABLES

Biking
-------
Id
WhoWasBiking
ForHowLong
WhatBike
Color
ActivityLogId

Jogging
--------
Id
WhoWasJogging
ForHowLong
WhatShoesWereTheyWearing
ActivityLogId

Singing
--------
Id
WhoWasSinging
WhichSong
ActivityLogId
```

**Notes**

Please note that in **Design 3**, I have removed the `ActivityDetailId` from the `ActivityLog` table. Only the activity detail tables have a link back to the `ActivityLog` table because they each store the `ActivityLogId`.

In this scheme, when a new activity happens, I will first insert a new row in the `ActivityLog` table, then insert a row in the relevant activity detail table with the `ActivityLogId`.

**Design 4**

```
ActivityType
--------------
Id  -- (int primary key identity(1, 1))
ShortName -- (For e.g. 'Biking', 'Jogging', 'Singing', etc.)
ActivityDetailTableName -- ('Biking', 'Jogging', 'Singing', etc. Please 
                        --   see the activity detail tables below)


ActivityLog
------------
Id
ActivityTypeId
DateTimeWhenItHappened


ACTIVITY DETAIL TABLES

Biking
-------
Id
WhoWasBiking
ForHowLong
WhatBike
Color

Jogging
--------
Id
WhoWasJogging
ForHowLong
WhatShoesWereTheyWearing

Singing
--------
Id
WhoWasSinging
WhichSong


ActivityActivityDetail
------------------------
ActivityId
ActivityDetailId
```

**Notes**

In Design 4, neither the `ActivityLog` nor the activity detail tables have a foreign key. There's instead a link table named `ActivityActivityDetail` that has a composite primary key comprising of the primary keys of the `ActivityLog` table and the relevant activity detail table.

**Assumptions:**

1. And assuming my primary concern is to optimize insertion time and not querying time, which of the above designs is better?
2. Assuming I want to be able to answer questions such as:

a. What all activities happened between this time and this time today? Please show me everything about each activity that happened like so:

```
When     Activity  WhoWasDoingIt  WhatShoesWereTheyWearing WhatBike Color  WhichSong
1:28 PM  Jogging   Jake           Nike                     NULL     NULL    NULL
4:00 PM  Singing   John           NULL                     NULL     NULL    Ooo laa laa laa laa laa
4:30 PM  Biking   Jane            NULL                     Atlas     Red    NULL
...
```

b. What biking happened today and at what times?

**No Non-Clustered Indices for Foreign Keys**

Please also observe that there are no non-clustered indices created for foreign keys. Should I be creating them?

Though in general, the more the number of indices, the costlier the insertion. However, in this specific instance, will the non-clustered indices on foreign keys help improve insertion time over querying time?

**Specific Database Product**

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Comment: All I can say is that most of the time the insert performance impact caused by indexes is overstated. It's really not that noticeable